# At what point is my picture from camera being scaled down?

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, surfaceview

I have been going on circles for this for awhile. I have a fullscreen camera preview on a surfaceview. The quality looks good. I need to freeze the image on user click and then put an imageview on top of the surfaceview (it needs to be an image view because there are farther manipulations done to it that can't be done with a surface view).

However, when I use the code below it works but the final bitmap project on the surface view is low quality.

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("pictureTemp.png", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        out.write(data);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File XX = getFileStreamPath("pictureTemp.png");
    ImageView imageViewX = (ImageView) findViewById(8);
    imageViewX.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmapN = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(XX.toString(), options);
    imageViewX.setImageBitmap(bitmapN);
    SwitchCamIcons();

}


public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle){

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: The code above is missing the lines: Bitmap icon2 = RotateBitmap(bitmapN, 90); imageViewX.setImageBitmap(icon2); instead of using bitmapN

Comment: How do you choose the picture size for `takePicture()`? Maybe, the default size is too small for you.